# How do I report outages on the Microsoft Onedrive Javascript API

Tags: javascript, onedrive

The Microsoft Onedrive Javascript File Picker API version 6.0 is currently not working for Consumer Onedrive accounts.  When a file is selected and a user presses open, the message "The file couldn't be shared.  Please try again later" is presented.  This occurs on their demo site at https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v6/js-picker-overview.htm
as well.

Does anyone know how to report outages like these to the Microsoft OneDrive team?

Comment: We're investigating. You can report issues directly to us by logging into OneDrive, clicking on the ? in the title bar, and then clicking email OneDrive support.

Comment: Thanks. Just FYI before stack overflow I tried what you said and the support person just pointed me at the onedrive developer site which wasn't too helpful

Comment: I should mention that the problem is with Web Links.  Download Links work correctly.